# How can I disable or prevent Autofac from kicking in where it is unwanted?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac

I have a controller with a default constructor and a DI constructor:

```
#if PROTOTYPING
public class MyPrototypeController : Controller
{
    MyRandomDataGeneratorComponent generatorSeededTheWayINeed;
    public MyPrototypeController()
        : this(new MyRandomDataGeneratorComponent(DateTime.Now.Millisecond)
        /* whatever seed, I don't care */) {
    }
    public MyPrototypeController(MyRandomDataGeneratorComponent generatorSeededTheWayINeed) {
        /* DI for testing purposes, I need to be able to reproduce the same random situation */
        this.generatorSeededTheWayINeed = generatorSeededTheWayINeed;
    }
}
public class MyRandomDataGeneratorComponent
{
    public MyRandomDataGeneratorComponent(Int32 randomSeed)
    {
        /* use the seed to initialized the random generator */
    }
}
#endif
```

I expect the controller to be created by calling the default constructor. However Autofac thinks it so smart that it goes all the hard way around and uses the parameterized constructor, but it fails creating MyRandomDataGeneratorComponent because it cannot resolve the number.

God knows how annoying this is.

How can I tell this framework to use the default constructor or can I disable it for this controller altogether?

Comment: Why do you have multiple constructors in the first place? This is a [bad idea](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97).

Comment: If Autofac tries to create MyComponent, it means that MyComponent is registered in your container. Your comments indicate otherwise. What is the real state of your scenario? If that component is not in your container, I believe Autofac would choose the default constructor since it then does not "know" MyComponent.

Comment: @Steven, I added the default constructor, because I didn't want to bother with registration and I hoped with the default constructor it won't be a problem to create the controller even though the component isn't registered. The thing is the component is a temporary thing which is needed for development purposes only (a mock) and it is going to go away from the production code. This is why I want it to be involved as little as possible, still being able to inject it for testing purposes.

Comment: @PeterLillevold, I confirm, it is not registered (on purpose). The thing is the framework cannot make decisions on which constructor to use. If there is more than 1 then Autofac has to fail with the exception, saying don't known which one to use. Letting a black boxes make a decision for you is a are very dangerous practice. From what I can see the only way is to register MyComponent explicitly specifying the default constructor (which I don't want to do because it is a temporary thing that will go away eventually). Stupid framework!

Comment: I made some edits to make it clear about the purpose of the component.

Comment: @bonomo - To further help you, we need to see your Autofac registration code.

Answer (score 2):

**They answered above nemesv gave you the answer:**

ContainerBuilder.Register(c => new MyController()).AsSelf(); is the "switch to manual mode" in Autofac. Use that and it will work without changing your classes.

.AsSelf() is what you're looking for.

Comment: Is there an option to make this behaviour default? I wish I could configure Autofac so that it doesn't try to instantiate something it has no idea how to deal with. Without doing this explicit registration like you said.

Answer (score 1):

Autofac chooses the constructor that has the most dependencies that it knows how to resolve. It seems that `MyComponent` is registered, but it is registered incorrectly: you have not specified what `someNumber` should be. In other words, if you just tried `Resolve<MyComponent>()` you would have the same problem - `MyController` is not the root issue here.

There are a couple ways you could handle this. The easiest is to add a default constructor to `MyComponent`

```
public MyComponent() : this(DateTime.Now.Millisecond) { }
```

The second easiest is to adjust the `MyComponent` registration

```
containerBuilder.Register(c => new MyComponent(DateTime.Now.Milliseconds))
    .AsSelf();
```

You could also write the registration like this, to explicitly use the default constructor:

```
containerBuilder.Register(c => new MyController())
    .AsSelf();
```

You could also change your code so that `MyComponent` is not registered with Autofac at all, and then Autofac will not choose the `MyController(MyComponent component)` constructor, but this doesn't seem like the best solution.

**Edit**

These tests demonstrate that `MyRandomDataGeneratorComponent` (aka `MyComponent`) is actually registered. Please post your registration code if you need help figuring out how it got registered.

```
public class MyController
{
    MyRandomDataGeneratorComponent generatorSeededTheWayINeed;
    public MyController()
        : this(new MyRandomDataGeneratorComponent(DateTime.Now.Millisecond)
            /* whatever seed, I don't care */)
    {
    }
    public MyController(MyRandomDataGeneratorComponent generatorSeededTheWayINeed)
    {
        /* DI for testing purposes, I need to be able to reproduce the same random situation */
        this.generatorSeededTheWayINeed = generatorSeededTheWayINeed;
    }
}
public class MyRandomDataGeneratorComponent
{
    public MyRandomDataGeneratorComponent(Int32 randomSeed)
    {
        /* use the seed to initialized the random generator */
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void example1()
{
    var cb = new ContainerBuilder();
    cb.RegisterType<MyController>().AsSelf();
    var container = cb.Build();

    Assert.IsFalse(container.IsRegistered<MyRandomDataGeneratorComponent>());
    // since MyRandomDataGeneratorComponent is not registered,
    // the default constructor is used
    var instance = container.Resolve<MyController>();
}

[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException))]
public void example2()
{
    var cb = new ContainerBuilder();
    cb.RegisterType<MyController>().AsSelf();
    cb.RegisterType<MyRandomDataGeneratorComponent>().AsSelf();
    var container = cb.Build();

    Assert.IsTrue(container.IsRegistered<MyRandomDataGeneratorComponent>());
    // since MyRandomDataGeneratorComponent is registered, Autofac
    // uses that constructor, but cannot resolve parameter "randomSeed"
    try
    {
        var instance = container.Resolve<MyController>();
    }
    catch (Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException ex)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(ex.Message.Contains(
            "Cannot resolve parameter 'Int32 randomSeed'"));
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: MyComponent is NOT registered with autofac

Comment: Please do not suggest me to alter my classes just to make Autofac work. I convinced it's the framework that has to revolve around my needs, not the opposite. Inability to be shut down or switched to manual mode is an indicator of a poorly designed framework.

Comment: @bonomo the third sample: `vontainerBuilder.Register(c => new MyController()).AsSelf();` is the "switch to manual mode" in Autofac. Use that and it will work without changing your classes.

Comment: If the exception says something like "cannot resolve parameter 'someNumber' of MyComponent" then MyComponent IS registered. (Otherwise the exception would say something like "MyComponent is not registered") Perhaps you are using the "any concrete type not already registered" source?

Comment: I swear god MyComponent is not registered. This is the very reason why I added the default constructor, because I didn't want to bother with registration and I hoped with the default constructor it won't be a problem to create the controller even though the component isn't registered. The thing is the component is a temporary thing which is needed for development purposes only (a mock) and it is going to go away from the production code. This is why I want it to be involved as little as possible, still being able to inject it for testing purposes.

Comment: @nemesv, Nice. This is what I tried to avoid. If this is the case then I just remove the second constructor so that Autofac doesn't see it although DI won't be possible this way.

Comment: @bonomo see update - I am sure that MyComponent IS registered.

Comment: @default.kramer, this doesn't make sense, I created both the controller and the component myself, and I didn't do anything else, if the MyRandomDataGenerator component got somehow registered, it was done by the framework without asking me, which raises another question where this could happen and how can I disabled it

Comment: @bonomo perhaps you should ask another question and post your registration code. You might be doing something like `RegisterAssemblyTypes().AsSelf()` which would register all concrete classes. There are also other ways this could happen. I can't say without seeing your registration code.